# Helm-occur: How edit result?

Tags: helm

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1, Helm

I want to find text "**test3**". So I use `helm-occur`

[image]

As result I get 5 candidates. Nice.

Now I want to edit text direct in buffer ***helm-occur***.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 3):

Install the package `wgrep-helm`, then

1. Save the occur result to a separate buffer with <kbd>C-x C-s</kbd> (`helm-moccur-run-save-buffer`)
2. Change to wgrep mode with <kbd>C-c C-p</kbd> (`wgrep-change-to-wgrep-mode`)
3. Edit the buffer like a normal buffer
4. Apply the changes with <kbd>C-x C-s</kbd> (`wgrep-finish-edit`)

By the way, the above is documented via <kbd>C-h m</kbd> (`helm-help`).

Comment: I need direct edit "Helm-occur" AND as result the buffer "text.txt" to change "on fly". Is it possible?

Comment: Maybe better use package "Emacs-wgrep" because "wgrep-helm" was closed ?

Comment: @Alexei The package name is [`wgrep-helm`](https://melpa.org/#/wgrep-helm), which is provided by the project [Emacs-wgrep](https://github.com/mhayashi1120/Emacs-wgrep).

Comment: Can one put `C-x C-s`  to action list? And how to bind `C-c C-p` in the "save buffer" mode?

Comment: @theldoria `C-x C-s` is a normal Emacs command, not a helm action. It doesn't make sense to add it to the action list. `C-c C-p` is the default binding out of box (assuming you are a package.el user and having the package wgrep-helm installed.).

Comment: @xuchunyang not true. Of course, you can override such keystrokes to the local buffer. A key stroke is not a command.